# ¿Como bloquear el teclado? y obtener las datos de una lectora de codigos de barras

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes tengo una lectora de códigos de etiquetas la cual mete los datos del código en un imput en mi formulario lo que hice fue bloquear las letras y los números del teclado exceptuando los códigos que la lectora mete en el imput mi código es el siguiente

```
function onKeyDownHandler(event) {
    var codigo = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if(codigo >= 48 && codigo <= 59 || codigo==173 || codigo==13 || codigo==40 || codigo==189 || codigo==9) { //aqui estan los codigos que la lectora usa
    }else{
        event.preventDefault();
    alert("esta acción está prohibida");
    }

    var pressedKey = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    if (event.ctrlKey && (pressedKey == "c" || 
                          pressedKey == "v")) {
      event.returnValue = false; //tambien quite la opcion de copiar y pegar con cv
    }
}
```

mi pregunta es ¿como podrida hacer para que solamente se pueda recibir los datos de la lectora sin dar la opción de también meterlos por el teclado?

El código que normalmente usamos contiene solo números y un guion normal como este : 1000000000051-1

Comment: No veo mucho problema en que se metan manualmente. Supón un escenario donde el lector falle (se rompió el cable) y necesitas ingresar códigos. Seria bueno tener opción de ingresar el código manual, no crees?

Comment: Hasta donde recuerdo, la lectora envía el código leído como si se hubiera introducido por teclado y, si bloqueas el teclado, no habrá entrada de datos.

Comment: anguel tienes razón no lo había pensado

Comment: y no sabia eso triby muchas gracias